# Now Windows 8 is not showing at the time of boot loading but showed a couple of days ago

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-8

On my machine, I have `Windows 8` and `Ubuntu 20.04`. Everything was going smoothly. At the time power on or restart, I was getting 2 options to choose from (Windows or Ubuntu).

Due to COVID-19, I installed AnyDesk (a remote desktop software) to work from home. AnyDesk was showing some error and after searching `Google`, `StackOverflow`, and so on, I have changed something on the BIOS. What I changed, I forgot.

Now, at the time of power on, I have no options for `Windows`. The system directly loading as Ubuntu.

I have gone through every post of the `askubuntu` regarding this issue (i.e, `how to add windows in the grub`, `os-prober`, `update-grub`), etc and applied the suggested answer. But nothing is working. Even I tried the `Boot Repair` software (no luck).

The output of the `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     264191     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2     264192  782446591  782182400  373G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  782446592  783497215    1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sda4  783497216 3907028991 3123531776  1.5T Linux filesystem
```

The output of the `sudo update-grub`

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

A portion of the output from the `Boot Repair` software

```
============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 has 
                       2742886399 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 15627788287 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

The full output of the `Boot Repair` software
[File link](https://ufile.io/dyc6tnp9)

You can see that the windows is found at `sda2` but when I am using `sudo update-grub` this is not adding in the boot menu.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**Update**

If I press `F12`, I am getting 2 options `Ubuntu` and `Windows boot manager`. From the `Windows boot manager` I can do start `Windows`. Now, is it possible to get the 2 options from `grub` without pressing `F12`? Please see the attached image.

[image: F12 Options]

Comment: *I have changed something on the BIOS. What I changed, I forgot.* -- The issue is probably there. Try to undo the change in BIOS settings. It seems that `sudo update-grub` cannot not find Windows anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any command to undo the BIOS setting?

Comment: Some UEFI will list what changes were made when you save changes. But that is up to you to document those changes. It may just be a Windows update which turned Fast Start up back on which it does with updates. That sets hibernation flag and prevents NTFS driver & grub then from seeing your Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: BIOS is your motherboard firmware. It is not controlled by Ubuntu or any other operating system. All motherboards are different. We can't advise on how to manage your motherboard firmware, but the motherboard manufacturer usually publishes documentation about how to use its features

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Please have a look and let me know if you have suggestions. Thanks